# Spring cloud, auth-service

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Создаю приложение на микросервисной архитектуре с использованием Spring Boot, Spring Cloud. Как пример я смотрю вот этот [репозиторий](https://github.com/sqshq/piggymetrics). Возникает вопрос с auth-service, вернее как идет обращение из account-service([AccountController](https://github.com/sqshq/piggymetrics/blob/master/account-service/src/main/java/com/piggymetrics/account/controller/AccountController.java)) в auth-service? И что нам идет в ответ?
Если это указывается где-то в конфигурациях, подскажите пожалуйста где искать)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно прописывать секьюрити конфиги сразу в нашем сервисе или же создать и зарегестрировать в еврике конфиг сервис. В этом репозиторие это находиться [здесь](https://github.com/sqshq/piggymetrics/tree/master/config).